# This is a question about setting up routing routes

Tags: reactjs, routes

```
        import React from 'react'; 
    import {Link, Route, BrowserRouter as Router, Switch} from "react-router-dom";
    import './App.css';
    import User from './Component/User';
    import AdContent from './Component/AdContent';
    //Home.js
    function Home(){
        return(
        <Router>
          <header>
            <div>ShareAdsLink</div>
            <nav>
                <Link to="/User">
                  <li className="button">LogIn</li>
                </Link>
                <Link to="/AdContent">
                  <li className="button">SignUp</li>
                </Link>
            </nav>
          </header>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/User" component={User} />
            <Route path="/Adcontent" component={AdContent}/>
          </Switch> 
    </Router>
    );
}export default Home;



    //App.js
import React from 'react';
import Home from './Home';
import {Route, BrowserRouter as Router, Switch} from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Route path="/" component={Home} exact/>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

What I'm trying to do is to show the default screen (the page you see as soon as you enter) in `Home`.
There are login and signup buttons in `Home`, and if i click this button, a new page should appear. But in my results, a new page should be opened, separate from the contents of `Home`, but the contents of `Home` will be displayed too.
How can I display a new page? Using exact keywords is useless.

That is my first question.
Secondly, can you give me advice on where(ex, App.js ,,) to configure the base screen?

Comment: Hi @bover I suggest you use routing like this https://github.com/kantivekariya/react-antdesign-redux-reducer.

Answer (score 0):

Restructuring your app like this should help:

```
//App.js
import React from "react";
import Home from "./Home";
import { Route, BrowserRouter as Router, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import User from "./Component/User";
import AdContent from "./Component/AdContent";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/User" component={User} />
        <Route path="/Adcontent" component={AdContent} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;

//Home.jsx
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

function Home() {
  return (
    <header>
      <div>ShareAdsLink</div>
      <nav>
        <Link to="/User">
          <li className="button">LogIn</li>
        </Link>
        <Link to="/AdContent">
          <li className="button">SignUp</li>
        </Link>
      </nav>
    </header>
  );
}
export default Home;
```

Comment: Thank you! It runs normally. If you're okay, can you tell me the problem with my code?

Comment: You see, you have got two <Router>s; One in the App component and the other in the Home component. And the Route in the App component is always being matched exactly! which in turn renders the Home component which has its own Router & Routes!

Comment: If it helped you solve your problem please do mark it as accepted so that others may know too. :)

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

You are rendering your homepage header no matter what, regardless of path/page.

## Solution

Just render the header content into its own route within the `Switch`, and move the routes into `App`. By placing the less specific home path (`"/"`) last/later then more specific paths will be attempted to be matched first, and if no prior path is matched then the header will render.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/User" component={User} />
        <Route path="/Adcontent" component={AdContent} />
        <Route path="/">
          <header>
            <div>ShareAdsLink</div>
            <nav>
              <Link to="/User">
                <li className="button">LogIn</li>
              </Link>
              <Link to="/AdContent">
                <li className="button">SignUp</li>
              </Link>
            </nav>
          </header>
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! Happy to know another way with good advice. Have a nice day :)